# Is it allowed to place ...<T> as class name java?

Tags: java

I have this code for a class that represent a element in a list

```
public class Element<T>{
   Element<T> next;
   Element<T> previous;
   T info;
}
```

I have some ideas but I actually don't  figure out the full meaning of the above declaration. And have some hard times to search for an explanation of this technique.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: These are generics. Your usage is correct. Google for it, as this question is to broad.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I suppose so, though I have evolved the opinion that StackOverflow might have become overly hostile for at least some "entry level questions" even if duplicated.

Comment: Sorry but without knowing it is called generics. It is not easy to google. Or search in SO questions

Comment: @koalaok: You're right, it's hard to google something that you don't really know the name of, especially if the thing uses special characters. And that's perfectly ok. You learned now :) Btw, the characters are called "angle brackets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<T>` is a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), the class name is simply `Element`.  Generics are a bit of a complex topic, but the code you've posted looks valid.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the class is     `Element`

```
<T>
```

indicates that it's a generic class. When you use it you have to parameterize it:

```
Element <Object> e = new Element<Object>();
```

Every occurrence of

```
<T>
```

in the class, will be replaced with Object (you could put whatever class type you want instead of Object, but not a primitive type)